# Why page is reloaded after key.enter Angular?

Tags: angular

My template is:

```
<form class="navbar-form">
    <div class="input-group no-border">
        <input type="text" #term class="form-control" (keyup.enter)="search($event)" placeholder="поиск..." />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon" (click)="search($event)">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
            <div class="ripple-container"></div>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Method search() is:

```
 search(e): boolean {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.router.navigate(['users']);
}
```

Why despite  `e.preventDefault();` page is reloaded after enter key pressed?

I have removed `(keyup.enter)="search($event)"` it still reload page. It means somewhere else events called

Comment: Because ```preventDefault()``` affects only the event, but not the code after.

Comment: I know, but instead moving to route page I get reload page.

Comment: Then, I would assume, that issue connected to your routing setup. Could you post it here?

Comment: I commented `this.router.navigate(['users']);` the same problem

Comment: Probably, you should remove the return type as long as the function returns nothing.  I just tested your code (without the router) does reload. I suspect you have a routing problem, can you post your routing config please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "double elimination" strategy to completly stop the event:

```
e.preventDefault(); 
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: When I do click it work fine, when key.enter it reloads

Comment: Is it all code? Remove search from the input and check once more

Comment: I have removed, it still reloaded, how to find where is catcher?

Comment: One more try please, change <form> tag to <div> and do one more test

Comment: I have faced with another problem when I try to use `this.router.navigate([urlRedirect]);` already in this page. So routing does not work.

Comment: What is the second issue?

Comment: I try to route to the same page. For that I pass as paramater time() `this.router.navigate([urlRedirect], { queryParams: { t: time } });` But page is not reloaded.

Comment: May be it is better to open another question? Btw, @Suren answer is way better than my :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `<form>` is handling the `keydown` event before the `<input>` does, so you can use `keydown.enter` on your `<input>` instead.

Also, your function does not quite return `boolean`, you can use `void` there (this doesn't apply to your question, just advice).

component.html

```
<form class="navbar-form" >
   <div class="input-group no-border">
     <input type="text" #term class="form-control" 
         (keydown.enter)="search($event)" placeholder="поиск..." />
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon" 
         (click)="search($event)">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
          <div class="ripple-container"></div>
     </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
  search(e): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.router.navigate(['users']);
  }
```

Comment: If you still need to use keyup and not keydown you can add to the form something like this <form (submit)="$event.preventDefault()"> .